# Access button index from TableView inside another TableView

Tags: ios, swift, button, tableview, indexpath

I have a TableView inside Another TableView, and the inner tableView contains buttons. I am able fire a method when click on button, but not able to get the indexPath. The app is getting crashed when I use the below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as! MyCell 
    cell.myButton?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(myButtonPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside) 
    return cell   
}

@objc func myButtonButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
    let clasObj = myCell()
    let indexPath = myCell.InsidetabView.indexPath(for: cell!)
    let index = (indexPath?.row)!
    print(index) 
}
```

Comment: If you don't want crashes, stop using `!` to force-unwrap nil values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave tag to the button on `TableView, cellForRowAt indexPath` Method and accessed it on `buttonPressed` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as! MyCell 
    cell.myButton?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(myButtonPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside) 

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell   
}

@objc func myButtonButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    let row = button!.tag
}
```